# Do patents prevent individuals from making a product out of patented invention for personal use?

Tags: patent-infringement, patent-infringment

Do patents prevent individuals from making a product out of patented invention for personal use?

If they do in fact prevent individuals from doing so, how can this be enforced?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - patents give the patent is the right to try to stop others from making, selling, offering for sale, importing and using.

Very unlikely to be any enforcement. But I have heard of someone who modified a jet ski to shoot him in the air on a stream of water who got a serious sounding cease and desist letter because it made the local papers.